# find the last record by Person

Tags: sql

This is my Data

```
Id Name Amt

1  ABC  20
2  XYZ  30
3  ABC  25
4  PQR  50
5  XYZ  75
6  PQR  40
```

I want the last record by every particular Name like :

```
3  ABC  25
5  XYZ  75 
6  PQR  40
```

I tried group by, but i am missing some thing.

```
SELECT     PatientID, Balance, PReceiptNo
FROM         tblPayment
GROUP BY PatientID, Balance, PReceiptNo
```

Comment: what RDBMS? SQLServer, MySQL? PostgreSQL?

Comment: By "last" do you mean "with the highest value of id"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM tblPayment p1
LEFT JOIN tblPayment p2 ON p1.Name = p2.Name AND p1.Id < p2.Id
WHERE p2.Id IS NULL;
```

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d8a5/2)

Comment: it is giving all the records

Comment: all the six records were displayed whereas i want only the last record  of that particular Person as i have shown in my Second record

Answer (score 1):

Should be similar to:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    amt
FROM
    myTable mt1
where mt1.id = (
                    SELECT 
                        MAX(id) 
                    FROM myTable mt2 
                    WHERE mt2.name = mt1.name
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
select * from (select id, name,amount from test order by id desc)as t1 group by name;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ba6ed/1)

Comment: This one will not work in SQL Server for example, not sure about Postgres

Answer (score 0):

One more option

```
SELECT *
FROM tblPayment p1
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM tblPayment p2
              WHERE p1.Name = p2.Name
              HAVING MAX(p2.Id) = p1.Id
              )
```

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d8a5/12)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
Select p.* 
from tblPayment p
Inner join ( 
  Select name, max(id) as id
  From tblPayment 
  Group by name
) as latest on latest.id = p.id
```